# How to call GDAL Hillshade from C++

Tags: c++, api, gdal

I am writing a C++ application that uses the open source GDAL spatial library. There is a commandline executable that comes with GDAL called gdaldem. It's capable of producing HillShade rasters for digital elevation models.

Can someone please tell me how to call the HillShade from code, through the GDAL API. I want to call the API directly and not use the command line executable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this isn't part of the libgdal API. However, you can "borrow" parts of [gdaldem.cpp](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/apps/gdaldem.cpp), such as the structures and functions used for processing the hillshade.